# Find the inverses of the following elements:

Tags: ring-theory

I want to find the inverses of:

1) $x^2+x+1$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{11}[x]/\langle x^3-x+3\rangle$.

2) $1+2^{\frac{1}{3}}$ in the ring $\mathbb{Q}[2^{\frac{1}{3}}]$.

How can I find the inverses without "guessing" and showing that what I "guessed" really is the inverse?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have polynomials $p(x), q(x)$ whose highest common factor is $1$. You can use the Euclidean Algorithm and Polynomial Division to find polynomials $r(x), s(x)$ with $$p(x)r(x)+q(x)s(x)=1$$

Now if you factor out $p(x)$ you find that $q(x)s(x)\equiv 1$ and that locates a multiplicative inverse for $q(x)$.

In the first case you can do this with $p(x)=x^3-x+3, q(x)=x^2+x+1$ (the Euclidean Algorithm will detect any common factor).

In the second case let $x=\sqrt[3] 2$ so that $x^3-2=0$ and you are looking for the inverse of $x+1$.

---

Note: in both cases your coefficients are taken from fields, which is straightforward. There are contexts in which unique factorisation fails or where a highest common factor cannot be assumed to exist.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! :D

Comment: How does it help me that I am looking for the inverse of $x+1$?

Comment: @sssss Take $p=x^3-2, q=x+1$

Comment: Because $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3] 2] \cong \mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^3-2\rangle$? Or what I jsut wrote is wrong?

Comment: @sssss That's right.

Comment: So I used that and found $\frac{1}{3}(x^2-x+1)$ to be the inverse. That means the inverse is $\sqrt[3] 4 -\sqrt[3] 2 +1$ but it can't be because it's not in the original ring.

Comment: @sssss $\sqrt [3][4]=(\sqrt [3] {2})^2$ so it is in the ring - in other language if $x$ is in the ring so is $x^2$, and so is $x^2-x+1$ - and you have rational coefficients.

Comment: I see, you are right I forgot about closure. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As a followup to Mark Bennet's answer, we may consider that

1. $x^3-x+3$ has no roots in $\mathbb{F}_{11}$ by direct inspection;
2. It follows that $x^3-x+3$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_{11}$ since its degree equals $3$;
3. It follows that $\mathbb{F}_{11}[x]/(x^3-x+3)$ is a finite field with $11^3$ elements, $\mathbb{F}_{11^3}$;
4. The multiplicative part of a finite field is a cyclic group, in our case with order $11^3-1$;
5. In a multiplicative group $G$ with order $n$, the inverse of $g\in G$ is simply given by $g^{n-1}$ by Lagrange's theorem;
6. Given $g=x^2+x+1$, $g^{-1}$ is given by the reduction $\!\!\pmod{11}$ and $\!\pmod{x^3-x+3}$ of $(x^2+x+1)^{11^3-1}$, so the problem can be solved by repeated squaring, due to $1330=10100110010_2$;
7. We may also use linear algebra. By regarding $\mathbb{F}_{11}[x]/(x^3-x+3)$ as a vector space with dimension $3$ over $\mathbb{F}_{11}$, with a base given by $1,x,x^2$, the multiplication by $x$ in $\mathbb{F}_{11^3}$ is encoded by the following (companion) matrix
   $$ M = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & -3 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\in\text{GL}_3(\mathbb{F}_{11})$$
   and the inverse of $x^2+x+1$ can be found by Gaussian elimination:
   $$ \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline & 1 & x & x^2 \\ \hline \cdot 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline \cdot x & -3 & 2 & 1 \\ \hline \cdot x^2 & -3 & -2 & 2 \\ \hline  \end{array} $$
   leads to
   $$ (1+x+x^2)\cdot (a+bx+cx^2) =  (a-3b-3c)+(a+2b-2c)x+(a+b+2c)x^2 $$
   in $F_{11}[x]/(x^3-x+3)$, so by solving a linear system in $\mathbb{F}_{11}$ we get that the inverse of $1+x+x^2$ is $\color{red}{5+4x+x^2}$.

---

The second question is simpler. The inverse of $1+x$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-2)$ can be found by noticing that
$$ x^3-2 = x^3+1-3 = (x+1)(x^2-x+1)-3 $$
so the product between $(1+x)$ and $\color{red}{\frac{1}{3}(1-x+x^2)}$ is $1$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-2)$.